# php - while loop error on a large data set

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm having some problems looping this script through a large database of 1m+ items. The script returns the size of an image in bytes from it's url and inserts the result into a database.

I get the browser error `Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on my test attempt. This doesn't bode well. Am I trying to loop through too many records with a while loop? Any methods for a fix?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysql_connect('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx') or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db('xxxx') or die("Could not select database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items");

if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ch = curl_init($row['bigimg']);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

        curl_close($ch);

        mysql_query("UPDATE items SET imgsize = '" . $info . "' WHERE id=" . $row['id'] . " LIMIT 1");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all, `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated. Please look at MySQLi or PDO. Secondly, who would want to loop over 1m+ records and cURL request them all?

Comment: Why can't you try the `shell_exec()` for the curl operations ?

Comment: So you want to make “1m+” individual HTTP requests in one script …?

Comment: @CBroe I'm interested in how to approach a task like this. Should it be segmented up into many smaller scripts? Any suggestions?

Comment: @KrisR how do I add shell_exec(), does it replace curl_exec() directly? Thanks.

Comment: You're making over one million cURL calls in a loop? Yikes!

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Yeah I know, a large loop! See my comment below ... would appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this problem at scale.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be related to the fact you are trying to call eachtime curl_exec. You might want to change your code to this in 2 parts: first retrieve the data from the database and then make the curl calls.

Comment: Then he would have two loops, instead of one.

Comment: it seems better since he has a lot of overhead with curl (response time etc.)

Comment: But why would that change by storing the database data in one loop, and then looping around the array you just created in a second loop? If anything all that will do is increase the overhead in PHP.

Comment: Let's step back and take a wider view of the problem -- is it that you're examining millions of images and getting their sizes to stick in a database? Is that really useful and worth all the traffic? If it is, are there lots of sites you're going to, or just a few? If the latter, is it possible to get permission to run something on those few site(s) to get the information? If not, I think you're going to want to spread out the calls to avoid overloading your server and maybe overloading your targets and getting blocked. Hopefully this is just a one-time effort!

Comment: We are starting a retail app that uses lists of products from a series of affiliate feeds. Such feeds have millions of products in them when combined, hence the large loop. We want to find and store the size of remote product images to better filter this product list. For example, there are many products in our feed which are provided with 'no image' placeholders that retailers place as substitute product images where a unique image cannot be provided. With image size information we can deduce these common placeholders and exclude them, keeping only products with unique images in the database.

Comment: @PhilPerry to answer specifically, we are looping through many sites and it will be a fairly frequent process to keep the data fresh. If anyone is in London and such a service interests you as a project, message me!